# Pandas: How to collapse a DataFrame to a single-row DataFrame instead of a Series on aggregation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Title says it all. I have some logic that works on rows and I would like to also use it on aggreations.

Say this is the data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]),
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c']) 


   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
2  1  2  3
```

What I want is the most native way to get

```
   a  b  c
0  3  6  9
```

I came across several solutions using `Series.to_frame()`, `.transform()`, initialize a new data frame with the Series' index as columns, etc. But is there some simple way I am missing?

In pure Numpy I usually use `x.sum(axis=0)[np.newaxis, :]` for that.

Comment: `df.sum().to_frame().T`

Comment: ``df.groupby([0, 0, 0]).sum()`` or ``df.groupby([0] * len(df)).sum()``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need transpose DataFrame from `Series`:

```
print (df.sum().to_frame().T)
   a  b  c
0  3  6  9
```

Or use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print (pd.DataFrame([df.sum()]))
   a  b  c
0  3  6  9
```